# Containerd list all containers through containerd.sock

Tags: containerd

I am looking for the way of listing containers in **containerd** through
***/run/containerd/containerd.sock***
in the same way as it is done for Docker https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/v1.41/#tag/Container/operation/ContainerList.

I have already tried

> grpcurl -proto /containerd/api/services/containers/v1/containers.proto
> -unix /run/containerd/containerd.sock containerd.services.containers.v1.Containers/List

And got the following error

> Failed to dial target host "/run/containerd/containerd.sock": tls:
> first record does not look like a TLS handshake

What am I doing wrong?